# multiple models with foreach loop asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreach, model

Thanks to stackoverflow I found a method to get multiple models in 1 view, but now I don't seem to be able to access it or something since my foreach loop gives an error.

My view:

```
@model IVH7B2.Models.adminPanelModel

 @foreach (IVH7B2.Models.adminPanelModel us in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@us.userl.userID</td>
        <td>@us.userl.UserName</td>
        <td>@us.userl.UserPassword</td>
```

in adminPanelModel is a user class that i need to acces so i can show all users on screen.

My model:

```
namespace IVH7B2.Models {
    public class adminPanelModel {
        public Users userl { get; set; }
        public NewsLetter newsl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I found out the answer, below was my fix:

```
@foreach (IVH7B2.Domain.Models.Users us in Model.userl ) {
```

Comment: How does this pass 2 models into your view?

Comment: i thought this part did    public class adminPanelModel {
        public Users userl { get; set; }
        public NewsLetter newsl { get; set; }
    }     IM a real asp noob....

Comment: you dont need to loop as it is not a list. just do @model.user1.userID

Comment: I think it's still one model, with multiple object/classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @foreach (IVH7B2.Domain.Models.Users us in Model.userl ) {
```

This answer above worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but maybe something along the lines of this:

```
    namespace IVH7B2.Models {
        public class User{
            public Name { get; set; }
            public Email { get; set; }
        }
        public class adminPanelModel{
              public List<Users>{get;set;}
        }
      }
@model IVH7B2.Models.adminPanelModel
@foreach ( Users in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Users.Name</td>
        <td>@Users.Email</td>
      </tr>
}
```